# Visualizar imagen en una rejilla de apex_application_temp_files

Tags: apex

Estoy creando una aplicación APEX para subir imágenes, pero antes de subirlas, las guardo en apex_application_temp_files.

Tengo una rejilla donde salen los registros de apex_application_temp_files, pero no consigo que se vea la imagen subida temporalmente.

El elemento 'Explorador de archivos' tiene el identificador P3_FILE_BROWSER y la sql para presentar la rejilla es:

```
select  ID,
        NAME,
        APPLICATION_ID,
        FILENAME,
        MIME_TYPE,
        decode(NVL(dbms_lob.getlength("BLOB_CONTENT"),0),0,NULL,'<img src = "' || apex_util.get_blob_file_src('P3_FILE_BROWSER',id) || '" width = "100"/>') as Picture,
        '<span onclick="eliminar_foto('''||ID||''') "  class="icono fa fa-trash"></span>' as eliminar
from apex_application_temp_files
```

¿Dónde está el fallo?

Answer (score 0):

En sí el uso de `'<img src = "' || apex_util.get_blob_file_src('P4_IMAGE',deptno) || '" width = "100"/>'  as Picture` esta bien. El problema es que los datos del formulario (id,..) los estás guardando en una tabla y la imagen en apex_application_temp_files.
Porque al hacer la misma consulta con una tabla, las imagenes se muestran correctamente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo único faltante puede ser, escapar los caracteres especiales para la columna:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Varios puntos a tener en cuenta:

1. Validar dónde se está guardando la imagen.
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
2. Si se guarda directamente en la tabla, en el IR puedes simplemente utilizar la siguiente consulta SQL, por ejemplo:

   select "DEPTNO","DNAME","LOC",sys.dbms_lob.getlength("IMAGE")"IMAGE"from "DEPT"
3. En la columna de imagen del IR, seleccionar el tipo de columna, tabla, columna BLOB y PK.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ten en cuenta que las imagenes se cargarán una vez se haya dado submit a la página.